# MySQL syntax error while creating a Trigger

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

After creating the following Trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER NUMERO_OS AFTER INSERT ON custom_values
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.custom_field_id = 4 AND NEW.customized_type = 'Issue' THEN

    SET @os = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(value FROM 1 FOR 3)) + 1 FROM custom_values WHERE customized_type = 'Issue' AND custom_field_id = 4 AND SUBSTRING(value FROM 5 FOR 8) = YEAR(CURDATE()));

    IF @os = NULL THEN

        @os = '001';

    END IF;

END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I get "syntax error near @os = '001';".

What should do i do to run MySQL Trigger ?

Comment: `if @os = NULL` isn't a syntax error, but it is a logical error.  That should be `IF @os IS NULL`.  This doesn't fix your immediate problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try repeating the `set`:

```
IF @os IS NULL THEN
    SET @os = '001';
END IF;
```